# piping split input into command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe

I'm trying to figure out a piping problem. my goal is something like this

```
replace $1 $2 index.html | split -d ':' | minify main.css
```

Where the output from main.css is

```
main.css:main.min.css
```

And index.html will go from this:

```
<link href="main.css" />
```

to this:

```
<link href="main.min.css" />
```

It's a simple example, I know, but I think it illustrates my problem.

- Edit 1

Okay, i got the piping the wrong way around, but I still can't figure this out.

here's a simpler example

```
echo 'foo:bar' | split -d ':' | replace $1 $2 -- index.html
```

is that kind of command possible?

- Edit 2

So close!

```
minify css/main.css | replace $(cut -f1 -) $(cut -f2 -) index.html
```

this would work except that for some reason cut can't read STDIN :( they are returning the correct values when run normally but I need them as arguments for the replace command

Comment: I think you got the pipeline the wrong way around. It flows from left to right, much like English.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with a one-liner, because you're trying to read input from two different sources (the pipe as well as an input file). Something like this might work, though:

```
IFS_SAVE=$IFS
IFS=: a=( `echo "foo:bar"` )
sed -i "s/${a[0]}/${a[1]}/g" index.html
IFS=$IFS_SAVE
```

The `IFS=:` instruction changes the [field separator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF) for the following command from newline to `:`, so that the nested `echo` puts two fields into the bash array `( ... )`. The array elements can be accessed like this: `${varname[index]}`

`sed -i` does an in-place replace in the file `index.html`. If you don't want that, remove the `-i` and redirect the output to a new file:

```
sed "s/${a[0]}/${a[1]}/g" index.html > output.html
```

Comment: You can shorten that using IFS: ```IFS=: a=(`echo "foo:bar"`)```
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)

Comment: The `IFS` remains as `:` after that line though, at least on my system.

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=: read -ra a <<<'foo:bar'
ed -s index.html <<EOF
g/${a}/s,,${a[1]}
w
EOF
```